# Infant traveling to US with grandparents

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, children

My infant (14 months old) is a US citizen with a valid passport. She’s currently in India (with a valid visa) and will be traveling with her grandparents in March (POE - San Francisco). We (parents) will be providing the necessary notarized authorization letter.

Will there be any immigration issue for the grandparents? Will the immigration officer question as to why she is traveling with them and there give less than 6 months of stay?

P.S. Grandparents have a valid US Visa

Comment: I'm confused.  Which one are you? 1) Citizen or 2) Permanent resident?

Comment: I am a Permant resident (hold a Green Card). My kid was born here, so a US citizen by birth.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a doubt that they have come to take care of the baby"?  Are they planning to say they are coming to take care of the baby and you're worried the officer won't believe them?  Alternatively, are you worried that taking care of a grandchild is somehow forbidden on a B visa?

Comment: No, they aren’t planning to say that they have come to take care of the baby. I am also not worried about the latter. All I am worried, are there chances of the visa officer getting a doubt (during immigration) that my parents (who are on B1) have come to take care of the baby, and therefore give them less than 6 months

Comment: Why would an immigration officer give less than six months to grandparents coming to take care of their grandchild?

Answer (score 2):

Anything is possible, but trouble at immigration strikes me as unlikely.  Foreign grandparents of US-citizen grandchildren visit the US on B visas all the time.  That they are traveling with the US-citizen grandchild would not have any logical bearing on their tendency or inclination to overstay or otherwise violate the conditions of their visitor status.

Whether the child's parents are US citizens, permanent residents, or (long-term) nonimmigrants should have no bearing on this.